# Finding an explicit matrix to conjugate an integer $2\times 2$ matrix of order 4

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a general integer matrix $2\times 2$ given by $A=\begin{pmatrix} a&c\\ b&d\end{pmatrix}$ which satisfies $A^4=I$. This implies that $A$ is $\mathsf{GL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$-similar to $B:=\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $d=-a$ and $c=-\frac{a^2+1}{b}$, so $A=\begin{pmatrix} a& -\frac{a^2+1}{b}\\ b &-a \end{pmatrix}$ with $b\mid a^2+1$.

**Problem** I want to find explicitly a general integer matrix $P$ that conjugates $A$ to $B$.

**Thoughts** I've put $P=\begin{pmatrix} p_1&p_2\\ p_3&p_4 \end{pmatrix}$ and I've found that $p_3=ap_1-\frac{a^2+1}{b} p_2, p_4=bp_1- ap_2$, and the determinant is equal to $$ \frac{b^2 p_1^2-2abp_1 p_2+p_2^2+p_2^2 a^2}{b},$$ which is equal to $bp_1^2-2ap_1p_2+p_2^2 \ell$ where $b\ell=a^2+1$.

Maybe it is too easy but I can't figure what are the correct values for $p_1$ and $p_2$ s.t $\det P=1$. Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is to write $p_1,p_2$ in terms of $a,b,c$ such that $$\begin{pmatrix}p_1&p_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b&-a\\-a&-c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p_1\\p_2\end{pmatrix}=1,\qquad (1)$$ where $a^2+bc=-1$. The integer solutions of this equation depend on the actual values of $a,b,c$.

For example, $A=\begin{pmatrix}3&-2\\5&-3\end{pmatrix}$ satisfies $A^4=I$ (or better, $A^2=-I$), and the integer solutions of $$5p_1^2-6p_1p_2-2p_2^2=1,\qquad(2)$$ can be found by the theory of quadratic forms: reduce the form using row operations:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}5&-3\\-3&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ so the original quadratic (2) becomes $P_1^2+P_2^2=1$ where $\begin{pmatrix}p_1\\ p_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}P_1\\ P_2\end{pmatrix}$. The four solutions $(P_1,P_2)=(\pm1,0)$ or $(0,\pm1)$ can be converted to the solutions for $(p_1,p_2)=\pm(1,1),\pm(1,2)$.

In general, the quadratic equation (1), $\mathbf{p}^*Q\mathbf{p}=1$, can similarly be converted using $R=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and its inverse/transpose, to get $R^{i_1}(R^*)^{i_2}\cdots R^{i_n}Q(R^*)^{i_n}\cdots (R^*)^{i_1}=I$. Note that $\det Q=1$ is preserved by these operations. Then $\mathbf{p}=(R^*\cdots R)\mathbf{P}$ gives $\mathbf{P}^*\mathbf{P}=I$, so $(P_1,P_2)=\pm(1,0),\pm(0,1)$. Thus the solutions for $p_1,p_2$ correspond precisely to finite sequences of $R,R^*,R^{-1},(R^*)^{-1}$ that reduce $Q$ to $I$. The algebraic relation between $p_1$ and $p_2$ (that would complement (2)) depends on this sequence and thus on $A$.